# Webpack 2: How do I generate a bundle.js from Bootstrap premade template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, npm, webpack-2

I want to generate a bundle.js from this pre-esxisting bootstrap template (it uses less)  https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2

I tried to generate it but I failed since the styles are never generated and the bundle.js is empty as you can see in the "dist" folder(This was expected since the index.js which is the entry point is empty as well. https://github.com/juanlet/webpack  . What should I do in order for webpack2 to include all the js,css and less files that came with the template and put it in a bundle.js?. Should I include every file on the index.js entry file?. I'm running out of ideas. Any article, documentation or instruction will be very welcomed. Thank you very much.

Comment: This template doesn't use webpack...are you trying to replace the gulp implentation with webpack?—and if so, can you show what you've done so far, please?

Comment: I know it doesn't use webpack, and yes, I'm trying to replace gulp with webpack. What I've done so far is on the 2nd link of my post, the webpack project, I just put everything on a folder and put the app.js file as the entry point but I don't know how to include every single file of the template into the resulting bundle.js

Comment: oh sorry i missed that link! let me take a look, sorry.

Comment: Your entry is `./src/js/api/index.js` but there's nothing in that file?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a noob in deployment tools. My main issue is that I have the index.html full of html code that I don't know where to put in order for webpack2 to put it in the bundle and also I don't know where to put the rest of the files of the template. I just don't know how to translate this template to be bundled by webpack.js, I've seen webpack2  tutorials on react but none of them tells you how to deal with a simple html5 web project, and it's notmentioned on the docs. All the tuts tells you to put a bundle.js tag on an empty html5 and none mentions a full html5 file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build this out with webpack, your first step is actually using whatever your entry point is to `import` or `require` other libs/files.

So, for example, if your entry point in your wepback.config.js is

```
entry: {
   bundle: './src/js/api/index.js',
   vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
},
```

Then that file needs to contain `imports` that you wish to include in that file. And then those files include other files and so on, until you have all your files bundled up through the root of your tree (index). In a very simple way, this is what webapack does: it imports/requires your files, bundles them, and loads them depending on your configuration.

In order to load/compile your LESS, you will either have to include it as an import in your JS files, or you could also use [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to generate a separate CSS bundle.

This is the best overview I can give to this question since I don't know the exact way your want to take your code and bundle it. Feel free to ask questions if you have them, and I will edit my answer to try and help answer them.

**EDIT**: This is an example of an older config I have extracting SASS into it's own file. It's using v1, but it more or less works the same for webpack 2. I just don't have an example with me right now: ([Here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/) is the documentation for using `extract` in v2. A little different, but not too much).

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',

    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        'babel-polyfill',
        './app/index',
    ],

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/public/'
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('public/app.css'),
        new DashboardPlugin(dashboard.setData)
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app')
        },

        // JSON
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loaders: ['json-loader']
        },

        // Img
        {
            test  : /\.(png|jpg|svg|eot|ttf|woff|raw)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=4096'
        },

        // Sass
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: [ 'style', 'css?sourceMap', 'postcss', 'sass?sourceMap' ]
        }]
    },

    postcss: [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })],
}
```

**MAJOR EDIT**:

An example repo exists here: https://github.com/thesublimeobject/webpack2example

Running webpack will bundle up your files, imported from an index.js file I created. This bundles all the external libraries which I installed via npm and removed them from the index.html file. I did not test any of the code that was generated since that's way beyond an answer to this question. Your LESS will also be bundled into the dist folder as a separate file you will need to provide a link to in the HTML (that's one thing I forgot to do is add links to the /dist, but I'm sure you can do that.

Comment: I just want the exact same output of the template you would see if you drop the folder using xampp, nothing fancy. So basically you're saying to me that this template it's a pain in the a... to "translate"  to webpack and that I should find another template or drop webpack?. What happens with the html content of the template?. Cause you only mentioned less and the js files but not the html that comes in index and all of the other html files

Comment: It won't be too much of a pain. All you have to do is use npm to install all of the vendor scripts, `import` then at the top, and then copy/paste the rest of the source code just in that file if that's okay with you. That will take care of the JS. For the LESS, if you just use `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, it should be pretty easy to generate a separate CSS file.

Comment: and for the html files?

Comment: could you make a fork and show me at least a couple of examples?. I really want to learn to use this but the docs doesn't give any info

Comment: The docs do give a lot of information, you just kind of have to dig deep and be already somewhat familiar with what you're doing, which is a tough hump to get over in the beginning. As far as the HTML files, if you're going to have separate ones, you can either include the bundle on every page, or use code-splitting to output different bundles for different pages. Webpack can't really do anything to combine HTML pages though, if you're wanting that. The server needs to have those to render for each request on the server. The only reason React can do that is because the HTML is generated.

Comment: Give me a few mins and I'll fork it and give it a try.

Comment: Edited with link to example repo!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this my friend. I guess I just missunderstood Webpack responsibilities. I thought it was used to bundle your whole project into a couple of files but that works only for javascript one page apps that has 99% of their code in javascript. In this case I had several html files, and the correct thing was bundling only the js and the css and put them on the footer of the html files. In my case I will use handlebars so no problem here, it's a one place change. I know it seems basic but now I can see it more clearly. Thanks

Comment: @Juan Very glad I could help! I know webpack can be a little daunting/confusing on a first run, so it's always nice to have a bit of a jump start.

Comment: I sure will after this. I've been listening to some podcasts and made the Stephen Grider course on webpack 2 https://www.udemy.com/webpack-2-the-complete-developers-guide/ today which was really good to understand the config file and optimization on resources as well...Thanks again